# How access to my old tables with different schema?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, ef-core-3.1

I had one `DbContext` with name `AppDbContext` in my `.net core` library.Now I decided to rename the current `AppDbContet` to `PoemDBContext` and change schema from `dbo` to `Poems`,And then I added another Library to this project that had Same Context Name As Old Context(AppDbContext), So my mistake was not to do these things step by step, So EF didn't make the right diagnosis in the changes I made to the project.Then I added a migration and update database.Now I have two version of tables For example I have

```
dbo.Poems
Poems.Poems
```

So I have run the project with no error But It didn't show the Poems ,Because new tables with Poems schema are empty.Now How can I access to my old table to copy them in my new tables?

```
[HttpGet("RandomPoem")]
public async Task<IActionResult> RandomPoem()
{ 
    int PoemNumber = jrng.GetInt(1, 459);//Get Random Number
    Poem UserPoem = db.Poems.Where(e => e.Number == PoemNumber).Include(e=>e.Hemistichs).FirstOrDefault();
    if (UserPoem ==null)
    {
         return BadRequest("Poem Not Found!");
    }
    return Ok((PoemModel)UserPoem);
}
```

How can I access to dbo.Poems table in ef core?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? Just a basic copy? INSERT INTO Poems.Poems SELECT * FROM dbo.Poems.

Comment: @Crowcoder I don't know sql . I want to read data with ef core 3.1.But I think in sql you are right.Yes I want to read data from dbo.Poems

Answer (score 0):

You need two DbContext and when you configure it you can choose schema.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Poems");
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```